# How to programmatically add correlation headers to Application Insights Angular http request

Tags: angular, correlation, azure-application-insights

I am using the npm package [@microsoft/applicationinsights-web](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@microsoft/applicationinsights-web) in an Angular application.

I have custom headers in my http service which are overriding the correlation headers ('Request-Id' and 'Request-Context').  I looked through the appInsights object, however was unable to locate these two properties to appended them to my custom headers.  Does anyone know how to get a handle on these programatically?

app insights config

```js
private appInsights = new ApplicationInsights({
    config: {
        instrumentationKey: environment.ApplicationInsightsInstrumentationKey
    }
});

this.appInsights.loadAppInsights();
```

http call

```js
getHttpOptions() {
    return {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
            'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
            'Pragma': 'no-cache',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            Authorization: `Bearer ${this.authService.authToken}`,
        })
    };
}

getDetails(): any {
    let detailsUrl = `${this.apiBaseUrl}${Details}`;
    return this._httpClientService.post<any>(detailsUrl, this.getHttpOptions()).pipe(
        catchError((e: any) => this.handleError(e, this)));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would need to see your code, but it sounds like you are saying that you are passing custom headers to the http calls, and that is causing the call to not include the Request-Id and Request-Context headers from AI. I may be bias.  I found this question because I thought that was happening for me as well.  The symptom I was seeing was: making http calls from an angular service with specific headers (Authorization in my case), and not seeing the expected AI headers on the request on the way out.

So I did some digging in to the AI Js repo and the value population for those is buried pretty deep, but what I did find was that it was turned off for GET requests by default (`config.disableFetchTracking = true`) and I was blindly only looking at the majority calls (GETs) while testing.

Once I turned that on, I started seeing it on all the requests that were not excluded by `correlationHeaderExcludedDomains`.

In the process I also tried setting the `distributedTracingMode` as suggested in another answer, and found that any value that included W3C (populating traceparent) was causing the values to not correlate correctly in AI. Specifically, the http function RequestTelemetry is correlated with the the PageViewTelemetry the angular request instead of the http call DependencyTelemetry.

I do see differences between the values in the `traceparent` and the `Request-Id` headers, so what it looks like from the outside is that the `traceparent` header is taking precedence and causing the parent on the function calls to be set wrong.
For now, Im keeping that feature off, and sticking with the default `AI` only.

As of this date, I am using the latest for both the JS library in my angular and the C# library in my function.

Comment: Exactly - I am passing custom headers into the http requests. I have updated the code above.  I looked into the distributedtracingmode, I am worried I will have to apply it to all my micro services so they correlate properly, and not ready to do that as well.  I will give your option a try and report back.  Basically from what you are saying just update that one property in the appinsights config "disableFetchTracking" to true and it'll start popping up.  Sounds like a piece of cake, thanks for the assist.

Comment: Here is the final approach, I didn't seem to get the result I was hoping for with the disableFetchTracking configured to false but left it on, I ended up with this configuration and am seeing the proper result now:

  private appInsights = new ApplicationInsights({
    config: {
      instrumentationKey: environment.ApplicationInsightsInstrumentationKey,
      disableTelemetry:
        environment.DisableApplicationInsights === 'false' ? false : true,
      disableFetchTracking: false,
      disableCorrelationHeaders: false,
      enableCorsCorrelation: true,
    },
  });

Answer (score 2):

Application Insights does not support custom correlation headers. We do recommend using [Trace-Context](https://www.w3.org/TR/trace-context/) standard everywhere and here is [how to](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/correlation#enable-w3c-distributed-tracing-support-for-web-apps) opt into it JS SDK